# Java serialversionUID warning: Trouble printing to screen

Tags: java, applet

I'm starting to learn java and working through tutorials but have run into a problem trying to do an animation of a digital clock. The code is:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Date;

public class DigitalClock extends java.applet.Applet {

  Font theFont = new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,24);
  Date theDate;

  public void start() {
    while (true) {
      theDate = new Date();
      repaint();
      try {Thread.sleep(1000); }
      catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setFont(theFont);
    g.drawString(theDate.toString(),10,50);
  }
}
```

And I'm viewing the applet using:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>This page has an applet on it</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>Digital Clock:
<BR>
<APPLET CODE = "DigitalClock.class" WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=100>
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm compiling with: 
    javac DigitalClock.java -Xlint

Which is giving the warning (no errors):

```
    DigitalClock.java:10: warning: [serial] serializable class DigitalClock has no definition of serialVersionUID
public class DigitalClock extends java.applet.Applet {
```

The animation is then not coming up at all (applet opens but nothing is in the window). I am assuming this has to do with the warning although from some research, I was assuming it means that the class is not getting called properly but I can't see why this is.

Please note: this is my first week working in java, I'm very very basic!

Thank you in advance for any advice you can give.

Comment: the warning is not your problem.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with applets but I'd guess that your problem is the `while(true)` in the `start()` method. You'd need some background worker to update the time instead.

Comment: To the OP: If any of the answers below helped, please accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

In front of everything. That should get rid of the warning.

Comment: Hmm this gives me a different error but would this also cause the issue of the applet not being painted to the screen?

Comment: Try adding an @Override annotation before the paint method. Does it give an error saying it can't be overridden?

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be ignored, is not the cause of not visualizing the applet. To solve the warning include this:

```
private static final long serialversionUID = 1L;
```

The applet tag is not supported by all browsers today, check http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_applet.asp, so be sure using a compliant one. Also put quotation marks in width and height values, like this:

```
<APPLET CODE = "DigitalClock.class" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate issues here.

The first is your warning: It's telling you that you don't have a `serialVersionUID`, which is just an ID used if you want to transmit instances of the class over the interwebs. Add this line to the beginning of the class and that should go away:

```
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Your second issue is that you are using a tag that isn't supported in Chrome, and isn't standard in HTML5, which means that it's gonna go away soon. Try using `<object>` instead.

What might also be causing it to fail to display is the fact that you have `while(true)` in the `start()` method. While I'm not familiar with how these things work, you might want to move that to a separate method in [another thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) so it's not blocking the `start()` method from completing, which could in turn be stopping it from rendering.

It's also better practice to keep the methods that update the time separate from the render anyway, since if your render lags, you don't want the time to stop being counted until it recovers. Your clock should be accurate even if the rendering stops for several minutes, since that's how clocks work.